# Returning the wrong MD5 String in Perl with Digest::MD5

Tags: perl, md5

I have attempted to encrypt this string with MD5:

```
lolno
```

I use the module use Digest::MD5 and my output was:

```
τ;å▌3Gùφ▄♥ H≤Gj╠
```

I know that this is not MD5 so Id like to ask how I could make this work?Here's the code I used:

```
use Digest::MD5;
$ctx = Digest::MD5->new;
$ctx->add($pass);
$digest = $ctx->digest;
print $digest;
```

I also tried:

```
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5);
$test = md5($pass);
print $test;
```

Comment: Your output should be a perfect MD5 checksum, but you didn't expect it to be printed that way. Most of the time, you want a hexadecimal representation. The line with `md5_hex` is right in the next line after `md5` in [Digest::MD5](http://p3rl.org/Digest::MD5)s synopsis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `md5_hex` (`hexdigest` for the first snippet) to see what you seem to expect. This is a binary representation presented as characters.